# Problem using react-native-track-player with a custom dev client

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, expo, avaudioplayer

I get this error when I try to use react-native-track-player in expo

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating ‘TrackPlayer.RATING_HEART’)

Invariant Violation: “main” has not been registered. This can happen if:
*** Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.**
*** A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn’t called.**

I deployed using expo-dev-client

Would you know what could be the problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try restarting Metro like the error suggests?

Comment: Yes but the error still there.